# AG-Grid-React: How to get column filter input value entered by user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to update redux mode after user entered the input in column filter but it not working

```
<AgGridReact
    rowData={rowData}
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    animateRows={true}
    onFilterChanged={(e) =>
        console.log("filter has changed", e)
    }
></AgGridReact>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysis i found solution to access filter user entered input in the following way

```
const onFilterChanged = useCallback(() => {
    const value = gridParams.api.getFilterModel()
    
}, [ gridParams, setFilterModel, filterModel ])

useEffect(() => {
    if (gridParams && !dataPending) {
        gridParams.api.addEventListener('filterChanged', onFilterChanged)
    }
}, [ gridParams, dataPending ])


<AgGridReact
    rowData={rowData}
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    animateRows={true}
></AgGridReact>
```